# Asp.Net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have a gridview with an enormous viewstate that I am attempting to shrink. I have turned the viewstate off in the control(which the gridview is in) but this seems to have done next to nothing in terms of the page size.

Now the gridview has buttons and dropdowns in it, which I know add to the size. But cannot be helped. Now short or rolling by own or overriding where the viewstate is stored is there any way to shrink the viewstate.

The gridview is also in an update pannel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gridview is so large I would advise you to use paging so the number of rows is kept to a minimum.

Comment: Strongly recomand study this article for custom paging and sorting : http://imar.spaanjaars.com/479/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-4-sorting-paging-and-filtering